# Does the charge of an atom vary over time due to electron orbits?

Tags: electrons, charge, atoms

I would guess if there is an effect it is very small but is there a reason to believe that there is absolutely no effect whatsoever?

EDIT: Why I think it might vary: because maybe all the electrons might be clustered on one side of the atom -- maybe this physical visualization is not valid.

Comment: There is no such thing as electron orbits, just the probability of an electron being in a particular place at a particular time.

Comment: @Sam perhaps we can say orbitals (or eigen functions). But I don't really see where the question is going anyway - since the charge on the atom, taken in this sense would be just the sum of the charges of the particles, which is constant. I don't see why the OP thinks it would vary.

Comment: Charge distribution might vary, rather than total charge.

Comment: @PonderStibbons The distribution would also be the same as all orbitals show symmetry in their arrangements.

Comment: *Why I think it might vary: because maybe all the electrons might be clustered on one side of the atom* First of all, electrons *repel* each other. Second, a charge on one side or a charge on the other side is the same charge. Maybe you really want to know whether atoms have electric dipole moments, which depend on where the charge *is*.

Comment: @Sam especially in an imposed electric or magnetic field, the orbitals are not always symmetric. (I mean do not always show the complete SO(3) symmetry).

Comment: @G.Smith yes, for example, an atom can at least become polar in the context of external electric fields - or within a molecule. (Are we worrying here about the distinction between atom and ion)?

Comment: Your question is sensible indeed. What exactly happens in an atom I don't know. I don't know very well the theory behind VdW and dispersive forces, too, but at least in molecular solids (so replace a single atom with atoms in a molecule, that does not look like a big step) those forces are true.

Answer (score 1):

Charge is conserved, so it doesn't vary.

Regarding a ground state stable atom using the Schrödinger Equation: the electron orbitals are stationary states, while their phase oscillates, the observable probability distribution does not.

Answer (score 0):

Atoms, do not forget, are neutral in total, as the nucleus has the opposite number of charges to the electrons.

Look at the possible [orbitals of the Hydrogen](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Chemical/eleorb.html) atom to get an idea of how probability makes also charge distributions:

[image: orbH]

When it comes to higher Z [atoms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_orbital) ( and [molecules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molecular_orbital)) the orbitals leave spaces in between lobes, which means there is a shape in the charge distribution. These shapes allow for the positive charge of the nucleus  to come through thus creating the bonds between atoms and molecules by the attraction of positive to negative.